# Android ignoring Locale change, using default strings.xml

Tags: android, locale

My app supports two languages, default is English and other one is simplified-chinese. I have created two values folder (`values` and `values-zh-rSG`) and have placed `strings.xml` files that contains strings respective to language.

In One of my `Activity` , user can change default language from English to chinese or chinese to English and than I reload the `MainActivity` again.
Locale is changed as when I check in `MainActivity` it displays simplified-chinese using following code:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
Log.d("checknl",config.getLocales().get(0).getDisplayName()) ;
```

But somehow, `strings.xml` from `values-zh-rSG` is ignored. It is always loading in English.

Please See: My `build.gradle` file doesn't contain "resConfigs "en"" in `build.gradle` (app) file.

I have tested this app on Android api 22 to 26. But it doesnt work in any.

Comment: Are you in Singapore region? It won't work outside of it or on emulators (afaik)

Comment: Yes,I have also tried using res/values-zh-rCN.But It did not work

Comment: why specifying region? try it with res/values-zh

Comment: tried that also..didnt work